# CakePHP 3: How to force either of two fields to be notEmpty using validation

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a model that requires one of two fields to be non-empty. Either one can be empty as long as the other one is not. I'm stuck on the best way to do this.

I can prevent *empty* entries like this:

```
$validator
        ->notEmpty('my_field', 'a or b must be non-empty', [$this, 'checkIfAorBisEmpty']);
```

The third parameter is a conditional function that returns `true` for the rule to be enforced only when the other field is also empty. But this only prevents things like this:

```
$this->Table->newEntity(['a'=>'', 'b'=>'', 'c'='foobar']);`
```

I want to also guard against something like this:

```
$this->Table->newEntity(['c'=>'foobar']);`
```

The code above will *not* prevent this because if the key is completely omitted from the saved data, then they have no effect. I can't use `requirePresence` because according to the docs, unlike notEmpty, it does not support a conditional function.

Apparently the application `buidRules()` aren't limited in the same way, but they don't run on `newEntity()`.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem... I was misunderstanding the way `newEntity()` and `save()` work. I thought newEntity was updating the DB, but I was mistaken. It runs the validations and returns an Entity object. Then the entity object needs to be saved... and THAT's when the build rules apply.

So the solution to my problem was actually the build rules. I just didn't know it yet. Although my question was misguided, I'm going to leave it here in case someone else encounters the same problem. The two-tiered validation system is one of the changes from CakePHP v2 to v3.